# Find the nearest value and its difference from an assay

Tags: python, arrays, r, linux, shell

I have a data table with values for each of A, B, C:

```
A      B        C
72764   115226  115364
74169   115387  119997
74770   120084  121022
77114   133818  103949
```

and I want to find the closest value and/or the difference in the closest value for each of these values in an array of X, Y, Z (+50 more variables):

```
X       Y       Z
84213   45661   111351
114406  114580  114580
114491  114825  114825
114880  NA      114876
```

preferably I'd like to print out something like this (where the distance to the closest variable in X to the A variable is printed):

```
A_X     A_Y
11449   -27103
10044   -28508
9443    -29109
7099    -31453
```

Perhaps it's because it's Easter and my brain is at half capacity, but I cannot figure out an easy and automated way of dealing with this issue. Sorry if this has been solved before, I could not find an answer on the webpage.

I'm fairly familiar with R and shell scripts in Linux, guess I can also try to solve it with a python script if anyone would be so kind as to help me.

Comment: Maybe just me, but I'm not sure what you mean by closest value / difference and how you calculated the values in `A_X` and `A_Y`

Comment: So in the case of `A_X` -> all A values match the `X` value 84213 -> consequently, differences shown in `A_X` are between the `A` values and 84213 (_the nearest hit_). I made an error calculating A_Y - now corrected. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Hehe, it is definitely me:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df` is your first dataframe, and `df2` your second, then you could do something like this...

```
sapply(df2,function(v) sapply(df$A,function(x) (v-x)[which.min(abs(x-v))]))

         X      Y     Z
[1,] 11449 -27103 38587
[2,] 10044 -28508 37182
[3,]  9443 -29109 36581
[4,]  7099 -31453 34237
```

Presumably you will then want to repeat across all columns of `df`, which would be something like

```
lapply(df, function(z) 
      sapply(df2, function(v) 
            sapply(z, function(x) (v-x)[which.min(abs(x-v))])))
```

The result would be a list of dataframes, one for each column of `df`

Comment: Hi again, is there a way I can modify your formula so that I can get two different results (in addition to the one you provided): **1)** get the closest value smaller than each value in A, B, C etc. and **2)** get the closest value larger than each value in A, B, C etc. I tried playing around with the _which.min_ and _abs_, but have as of yet been unable to solve it.

Comment: Try replacing the final function with `function(x) (v-x)[x<=v][which.min(abs((v-x)[x<=v]))]` - and another version with `x>=v` as appropriate

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrewGustar, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `combn` function. Cycling through and automating will be something like

```
pairs = combn(ncol(df2),ncol(df1))
for(i in 1:ncol(pairs)){
    column1 = df1[,pairs[1,i]]
    column2 = df2[,pairs[2,i]]
    #Do your difference/closest value calculations and store in results
}
```